# How to work efficiently with a compressed time series data set?

Tags: apache-spark, time-series, bigdata

The first part is just a very quick introduction on the data format I am working with and a few lines of code in order to create a fake data set which pretty much resembles the original data I have to work with.

---

**Create the Data:**

I am having a data set which takes the form:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create the data set

np.random.seed(42)

records = list()
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(10):        
        for k in range(1000):
            t = np.random.randint(pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01').value, pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01').value)
            if np.random.rand() > .95: continue
            records.append( (i, j, np.random.rand(), pd.Timestamp(t)) )

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
df.columns =['a_id', 'b_id', 'value', 'time']
```

which generates a *compressed* data set:

```
       a_id  b_id     value                          time
0         0     0  0.156019 2007-09-28 15:12:24.260596807
1         0     0  0.601115 2015-09-08 01:59:18.043399626
2         0     0  0.969910 2012-01-10 07:51:29.662492802
3         0     0  0.181825 2011-08-28 19:58:33.281289629
...     ...   ...       ...                           ...
47533     4     9  0.470582 2011-02-17 16:42:19.278101199
47534     4     9  0.186855 2000-07-19 08:19:16.652565603
47535     4     9  0.437264 2017-10-18 22:34:45.942782747
```

---

**The Data:**

The columnd `a_id` and `b_id` can be understood as the private key of a time series. In other words, one could get the entirety of a single time series where `(a_id, b_id) equals (0, 0)` by creating a pivot table like this:

```py
pd.pivot_table(df.set_index(['a_id', 'b_id']).loc[0, 0], 
               columns=['time'], values=['value']).T \
    .rename(columns={'value': 'Series ID: (0,0)'})
```

will give

```
                               Series ID: (0,0)
timestamp                                      
2000-01-03 11:37:27.821467132          0.522510
2000-01-04 20:04:25.320102707          0.598357
2000-01-16 08:11:41.275535866          0.146963
2000-01-23 00:26:48.847330863          0.840872
2000-01-23 06:53:48.530748946          0.492625
2000-01-23 08:08:58.594737501          0.637430
2000-01-29 18:12:31.061804272          0.046852
...                                         ...
```

---

In PySpark I can load this data by simply running:

```py
sql = SQLContext(sc)

df_data = sql.read.option("header", "true").schema(schema) \
             .csv(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, '*/data.csv'))
```

with the schema:

```
root
 |-- a_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- b_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

---

**The Problem:**

The problem I am having here is that I do not know how I should transform this data s.t. I can work with it more easily - like how can I extract the embedded time series in this `DataFrame`?

For example imagine I'd have to compute the correlations for all available time series. The first problem here is that I do not know how I can resample each time series in the compressed format in order to align them correctly for the computation of the correlation coefficient.

The biggest problem here is probably the resolution. Since the data goes over several years, I won't be able to simply resample the data on nanoseconds or join the time series on their timestamps.

It's more likely that I have to resample the data on hours and join the time series. But even then it is very likely that I have a lot of `None` values in between eating up storage space unnecessarily.

So.. I am very open for suggestions. I am aware that this is question is not fully on-topic here but after looking for a few days now, not able to find any sample code or suggestions on how to work with a data format like I got it here I hope that somebody on SO tosses me at least into the right direction here.

Thank you for any help and please let me know if I can provide more details!